# Trying to decide whether the sample is dependent or independent

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, independence, engineering-statistics

I have a problem deciding whether my data has dependant/pairwise or independant samples.

I have read multiple online guides now, but I can't figure it out:
I am testing about 10 different surface materials, which are placed outside for about half a year. In cold weather those materials begin to ice over. This icing behaviour is monitored by taking a picture every 30min. Using automatic image recognition the icing intensity on the samples was categorized from 0-4 at each one of those moments.

So my data looks like this:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{Material 1} & \text{Material 2} & \text{Material 3} \\ \hline
\text{TimeStamp 1} & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
\text{TimeStamp 2} & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\text{TimeStamp 3} & 3 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\text{TimeStamp 4} & 2 & 2 & 4 \\ \hline
\text{TimeStamp 5} & 2 & 3 & 3 \\ \hline
\text{TimeStamp 6} & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

My research question is if any of those materials shows significantly less icing. I can't figure out though if I have independant samples (requiring a Kruskal-Wallis-Test) or paired samples (requiring a Friedman-Test)?